# How to pass in API subdomain to ngResource?

Tags: angularjs, subdomain, ngresource, angularjs-ng-resource

I'm using ngResource to consume a RESTful API, and have implemented the following service:

```
app.factory('User', function($resource) {
  return $resource('/api/users/:id', { id: '@id' });
});
```

**I would like to pass in a subdomain to it. Is there a way to do this?**

I'm aware of the following workarounds:

1. Pass in a full URL: `api.acme.com/users/:id`
2. Inject a variable on the url: `'api.' + mydomain + '/users/:id'

With that said, I believe it'd be cleaner to just send the subdoman as an argument. Can this be done?